# Javascript loop to collect all forms on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I am having serious trouble with trying to get all the forms on a page to submit at once.  Each of the forms (there could be anywhere from 1 to 100) are generated using partial views with mvc3.  Each of the forms are generated using the @using (Ajax.BeginForm....   On the general 'save' button event handler in JS I have this code:

```
    var formsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

                for (var i = 0; i < formsCollection.length; i++) {

                    formsCollection[i].submit();
                }
```

Now, the mystifying and troubling part is that as written it only saves the last form in the last to the database.  Yet, when I put an alert in that loop, both get saved!

To further complicate matters when I click the general 'save' button the browser jumps to a blank page.  Now, I do have 'return new EmptyResult()' in the controller that handles the forms, but if I click the individual save buttons in the forms, it does not go to the blank page.

Any pointers in the right direction would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to submit more than 1 form?

Comment: What do you mean by a general Save button? Where is this button? Is it inside a form?

Comment: Forms are special, you can enumerate them via `document.forms`, but you can't submit all of them so easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a race condition. You are submitting two things at once, only one of them can actually make it.

You need to rethink your design.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up the only one being submitted issue.  I can see how this whole approach would be problematic.